# Empty bibliography and citation undefined

Tags: bibliography, texmaker

I'm writting my bachelor thesis and I encountered a problem with the bibliography. I've tried many different solutions (including changing Texmaker configurations, reinstallating Texmaker and so on). Nothing helped. There're always "Citation 'shabbir2010' [..] undefined" and "Empty bibliography" errors.

***my code:***

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{cytowania.bib}
\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}

my content \cite{shabbir2010}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

***my .bib file (from Google Scholar):***

```
@article{shabbir2010,

    author   = {Shabbir, G and Khan, H and Sadiq, MA},

    title    = {A note on Exact solution of SIR and SIS epidemic models},

    journal  = {arXiv preprint arXiv:1012.5035},

    date     = {2010},

    keywords = {trusted},
}
```

I have Windows 10 and Texmaker 5.0.4. Please help..